# Energy spent by motor in a period

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-fields

Consider a single coil that is turning in a constant and uniform magnetic field thanks to a motor. The normal to the coil is given by:

$${\bf u}(t)=\sin (\omega t){\bf u_x}+\cos(\omega t){\bf u_z}$$

How can we obtain the energy that the motor has to spend in a period $T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$?

I have thought that it could be given by the integral of -$U_p$ ($U_p$ is the potential energy of the coil) from 0 to T (we should have to integrate because the normal vector to the coil depend on t, I have thought). But I'm almost sure that it is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The magnetic flux through the coil due to the field is given by $\Phi(t)=\mathbf B\cdot\mathbf u(t)AN$ where $A$ is the cross-sectional area of the coil and $N$ is its winding number. I will assume a constant, homogeneous magnetic field of $\mathbf B=B_z\mathbf u_z$. Thus, by Faraday's law, the induced EMF in the coil will be

$U(t) = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt} = -\frac{d}{dt}\left(NAB_z\cos(\omega t)\right) = NAB_z\omega\sin(\omega t)$.

Unless you connect your coil to some resistor, no power will be drawn from the induced EMF and the coil will keep spinning forever without the motor having to do anything. (That is, of course, assuming a negligible internal resistance of the coil). Once a resistance $R$ is in place, by Ohm's law, $U=IR$, we get for the power

$P(t) = UI = U^2/R = \frac{(NAB_z\omega)^2}{R}\sin^2(\omega t)$.

This is the power which the resistor converts to heat and which was to be supplied by the motor. Now you are right that you have to integrate this over the time. I.e.

$E_{Period} = \int_0^TP(t)dt= \frac{(NAB_z)^2\omega\pi}{R}.$

It is actually more common to give the time-averaged power $\langle P\rangle=E_{Period}/T=\frac{(NAB_z\omega)^2}{2R}$, as $\langle\sin^2(\omega t)\rangle=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! So the potential magnetic energy of the coil is not linked to the energy given by the motor? And is all the energy given by the motor dissolved in the resistor?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'potential magnetic energy'. I'm positive that the energy is put out in the form of heat by the resistor.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Magnetic_potential_energy

Comment: I'm sure that the motor has to give the energy that will be dissolved in the resitor, but I'm not sure that the motor has to give only this quantity of energy

Comment: The Wikipedia article refers to the potential energy of a magnetic dipole. This would be relevant when you run a current through the coil and rotate it in the magnetic field. Here, the current is induced due to the motion.

Comment: Also, there will probably some other losses of energy. High frequency changing magnetic fields and currents are likely to emit EM radiation. However, the calculation I have given is typically what homework problems are after.

Comment: but we know that a coil is similar to a magnetic dipole (Ampere's equivalence principle)

Comment: Excuse me if I'm demanding. I'm asking you this aspect, because I have to find the energy given by the motor and the energy dissolved in the resistor. Then I have to comment if the two expression are compatible. So I have thought that maybe there is another "part" of enrgy given by the motor.

Comment: You can calculate the torque the motor has to provide to keep going directly by considering the Lorentz force on the electrons in the coil. Try it if you like, you'll find the same answer. It's a nice exercise anyway. Of course, there is always mechanical friction that comes to mind, but these things are usually neglected.